# Mysql запрос на вывод картинки к продукту

Tags: php, phpmyadmin

Не могу разобраться как имея две таблице в Базе данных, соединить их, и найти в ней подходящий товар, имея id самого продукта.
Дана таблица "products", в которой находятся поля "products_id", "products_title" и т.д.
Дана таблица "products_img", в которой находятся поля "img_id", "products_id" и т.д.

Пытаюсь сделать вот что:

```
public function getProductsById($productsid) {
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM `products`";
    $sql .= " LEFT JOIN `products_img` ON products.products_id=products_img.products_id";
    $sql .= " WHERE `products_id` = '" . (int)$productsid . "' LIMIT 1";
    
    $query = $this->db->query($sql);
    return $query->row;
}
```

Естественно при этом запросе выходит ошибка.

Comment: А текст ошибки секретный какой-то?

Comment: Fatal error: Uncaught ErrorException: Ошибка: Column 'products_id' in where clause is ambiguous<br>Номер ошибки: 1052<br>SELECT * FROM `products` LEFT JOIN `products_img` ON products.products_id=products_img.products_id WHERE `products_id` = '1' LIMIT 1 in W:\domains\localhost\engine\database\mysql.php:37

Comment: эта проблема конечно решается созданием дополнительной функции именно для таблицы с картинками, но хотелось бы узнать как сделать все одной функцией, если это возможно

Comment: Эта проблема решается __включением логики__. Вот ты написал `WHERE \`products_id\` = 1`. При этом у тебя и в таблице `products` и в таблице `products_img` есть поле `products_id`. Так вот подумай и ответь - как движок базы данных должен понять по какому из этих двух полей ты хочешь фильтровать?

Comment: я понял, спасибо